# Linq to Entities - Cast table object

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am using entity framework (database 1st) and I am having a few issues casting an entity as part of a linq to entities query, very new to this so any help would be appreciated..

Basically, I have 2 tables, 'tblContactTypes' and 'tblContactDetails', if I return a set of Contact Details, how can I return a Contact Type for each one? I can return an instance of the tblContactType class, but I am unsure how to return a Contact Type object.

My classes are as follows (the line I am trying to sort out is 'ContactType = x.tblContactType' in the GetAll() method) -

Data Layer -

```
public partial class tblContactType
{
    public tblContactType()
    {
        this.tblContactDetails = new HashSet<tblContactDetail>();
    }

    public int ContactTypeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ExpressionValidator { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<tblContactDetail> tblContactDetails { get; set; }
}


public partial class tblContactDetail
{
    public tblContactDetail()
    {
        this.tblCustomerContactDetails = new HashSet<tblCustomerContactDetail>();
    }

    public int ContactDetailID { get; set; }
    public string ContactDetail { get; set; }
    public int ContactTypeID { get; set; }

    public virtual tblContactType tblContactType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<tblCustomerContactDetail> tblCustomerContactDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Business Layer -

```
    public class ContactTypeVO
{
    public int ContactTypeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ExpressionValidator { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether this instance is new.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    ///   <c>true</c> if this instance is new; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </returns>
    public bool IsNew()
    {
        return ContactTypeID == 0;
    }
}

public class ContactDetailVO
{
    public int ContactDetailID { get; set; }
    public string ContactDetail { get; set; }
    public int ContactTypeID { get; set; }
    public tblContactType ContactType { get; set; }
    public ICollection<tblCustomerContactDetail> CustomerContactDetails { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether this instance is new.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    ///   <c>true</c> if this instance is new; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </returns>
    public bool IsNew()
    {
        return ContactDetailID == 0;
    }
}

    public class ContactDetailDAO : IDisposable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The repository
    /// </summary>
    public IContactDetailsRepository repository;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ContactDetailEO" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    public ContactDetailDAO()
    {
        repository = new ContactDetailsRepository();       
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Saves the specified contact detail.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="contactDetail">The contact detail.</param>
    public void Save(ContactDetailVO contactDetail)
    {
        if (this.IsValid())
        {
            if (contactDetail.IsNew())
            {
                repository.Add(new tblContactDetail
                {
                    ContactDetailID = contactDetail.ContactDetailID,
                    ContactDetail = contactDetail.ContactDetail,
                    ContactTypeID = contactDetail.ContactTypeID
                });
            }
            else
            {
                var saveItem = repository.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.ContactDetailID == contactDetail.ContactDetailID).FirstOrDefault();
                if (saveItem != null)
                {
                    saveItem.ContactDetailID = contactDetail.ContactDetailID;
                    saveItem.ContactDetail = contactDetail.ContactDetail;
                    saveItem.ContactTypeID = contactDetail.ContactTypeID;
                    repository.Update(saveItem);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // ERROR
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<ContactDetailVO> GetAll()
    {
        var contacts = repository.AsQueryable()
        .Select(x => new ContactDetailVO
        {
            ContactDetailID = x.ContactDetailID,
            ContactDetail = x.ContactDetail,
            ContactTypeID = x.ContactTypeID,
            ContactType = x.tblContactType,
        });

        return contacts.ToList();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the by ID.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The id.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ContactDetailVO GetByID(int id)
    {
        var contactDetail = repository.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.ContactDetailID == id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (contactDetail == null)
            return null;

        return new ContactDetailVO
        {
            ContactDetailID = contactDetail.ContactDetailID,
            ContactDetail = contactDetail.ContactDetail,
            ContactTypeID = contactDetail.ContactTypeID,
            ContactType = contactDetail.tblContactType
        };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether this instance is valid.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsValid()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code using the business layer ? Are you getting an error ? In the ContactDetailVO you provide also tbl* objects that are parts of the model, I think you must provide custom object if you want isolate business layer from data layer.

Comment: Thanks for the respose. The code above compiles and runs fine, but is returning the tbl object rather than the VO object, I think I am missing a cast somewhere but have managed to get myself totally lost... If I change the 'tblContactType' public property in 'ContactDetailVO' to be 'ContactTypeVO' I get a conversion error in the GetAll statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually build your ContactTypeVO object instance.  x.tblContactType is an instance of type tblContactType and it won't just magically convert to an instance of ContactTypeVO.

My suggestion here is to either implement a ContactTypeVO constructor that takes an instance of tblContactType and sets the properties appropriately or implement an implicit cast operator to do the same thing.

example of contructor method:

```
public ContactTypeVO( tblContactType object )
{
    ContactTypeId = object.ContactTypeId;
    <etc> = object.<etc>
}
```

then change ContactType = x.tblContactType to ContactType = new ContactTypeVO( x.tblContactType )

Comment: Thankyou, that makes sense. Got myself very lost with this yesterday!

Comment: You're welcome.  EF is confusing at first but then you "get it" and it's terrific.  Just need to work through all the gotchas the first time ;)